# PUT call on parameter-defined JSON

Tags: bash, put

I have a script that goes like this where "get_customers" is my pre-defined function and I have to pass each of the following four values as parameter to PUT call for all the customers. However, I am getting the error HTTP 400 Bad Request)","error":"ERROR_BAD_REQUEST" when running this. Anyone knows how I can pass JSON body using this for-loop in PUT call? Is my script wrong?

```
name=($(get_customers | jq --raw-output '.values[].name'))
tenantId=($(get_customers | jq --raw-output '.values[].tenantId'))
nodeId=($(get_customers | jq --raw-output '.values[].nodeId'))
d=($(get_customers | jq --raw-output '.values[].id'))

for (( i=0; i<${#name[@]}; i++ )); do
        
    
    curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer ${API_TOKEN}" -d '{"id":"${d[i]}","name":"${name[i]}","tenantId":"${tenantId[i]}","nodeId":"${nodeId[i]}"}'  -k "${URL}/api/file/files/${d[i]}"
    
    

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quotes, where variables are not expanded. Try this:

```
for (( i=0; i<${#name[@]}; i++ )); do
    curl -X PUT --header "Content-Type: application/json"\
                --header "Accept: application/json"\
                --header "Authorization: Bearer ${API_TOKEN}"\
         -d "$(cat << EOF
{"id":"${d[i]}","name":"${name[i]}","tenantId":"${tenantId[i]}","nodeId":"${nodeId[i]}"}
EOF
)" -k "${URL}/api/file/files/${d[i]}"
done
```